# ES6 - is there an elegant way to import all named exports but not the default export?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am looking for an elegant way to import all named exports without having to import the default as well.

In one file I am exporting many named constants plus a default:

```
// myModule.js
const myDefault = 'my default' 
export const named1 = 'named1' 
export const named2 = 'named2'
// many more named exports - otherwise this would not be an issue...
export default myDefault
```

In another file I would like to have an elegant way to import all named exports **only**, without having to import the default:

```
// anotherFile.js
// this is what I would like to do, but syntax is not supported, right?
import { * as namedOnly } from './myModule'
```

I do **not** want to:

```
// anotherFile.js
import myDefault, * as namedOnly from './myModule'
```

because I do not need the default in `anotherFile.js` and my linting tools bug me about
the defined but unused `myDefault`. Nor do I want to:

```
// anotherFile.js
import {
  named1,
  named2,
  ... // many more
} from './myModule'
```

because that's too much typing. I also do **not** want to `object.omit` the default:

```
// anotherFile.js
import omit from 'object.omit'
import * as all from './myModule'
const namedOnly = omit(all, 'default')
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I don't believe there's a shorter syntax for this.

Comment: There is no current syntax in the ES spec that allows this.

Comment: ok, thanks! I thought I might have missed it somehow... But would be nice to have, right?!

Comment: If you really want an elegant solution, do not mix named exports with default export. Choose one or another for your module, but not both.

Comment: What is your primary concern with `import * as myModule from './myModule' ;` with `myModule.named1` and such? Technically `myModule.default` exists, but you don't have to use it. Part of the issue is that the default export _is_ a named export, it's just named `default`.

Comment: @loganfsmyth my "concern" is that I want to loop over all named exports without having to remove/ignore the `default`...

Comment: It's not clear what you expect the import to do. Do you want the named exports as separate variables or as properties of a module namespace object? Your examples seem to mix the two arbitrarily.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There is no separation between "named" and "default" exports. The default export is a named export, it just happens to have the name `default` which is special-cased for ease of use by certain syntax.

The only way to import all of the exported keys is with

```
import * as foo from "foo";
```

and that will include the named export `default` if there is one. If you wish to exclude it from your checks, it would be up to you do handle that in your own logic, as you have done with your `omit()` example.

Comment: How can you convert foo to an Object? Apparently it's of type `Module`.

Comment: @tonix You could copy all of the properties off of it. It really depends on why it matters that it is a Module object instead of a plain object.

Answer (score 0):

ok so i using lodash !
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#omit

```js
import * as MDATA from './Modules.DATA.store';
{ defaultModuleData: _.map(_.omit(MDATA, ['default']), (ModClass) => new ModClass()) }
```

am not big fan and is not performance friendly but no choice !

Answer (score 0):

I'm using typescript 4.3.5, and it seems that the problem is solved now. I'm getting this from my linter:

`'export *' does not re-export a default.`