# Iterate imported JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I have problem with iterate of JSON imported object

```
    import * as countries from "all-countries-and-cities-json";

// obj with 152 keys, looks like:
//
// {
//   "Afghanistan": [
//     "Herat",
//     "Kabul",
//     "Kandahar",
//     "Molah",
//     "Rana",
//     "Shar",
//     "Sharif",
//     "Wazir Akbar Khan"
//   ],
//   "Albania": [
//     "Elbasan"...

    console.log(Object.keys(countries).length); // return 153 (152 + 'default')
    console.log(Object.keys(countries).pop()); // return 'default'
```

How to import this without key "default"?

Here is **tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
  }
}
```

You can see this behavior in [this live example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-k3d78r?file=tsconfig.json,stuff.json,index.ts) where a default property is added to the object.

Comment: What's the problem exactly?

Comment: Does the JSON not contain a field called `default`? What happens when you log `countries[default]`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ES6 - is there an elegant way to import all named exports but not the default export?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44258995/es6-is-there-an-elegant-way-to-import-all-named-exports-but-not-the-default-ex)

Comment: not contain, throw error
I use `continue` to avoid this, like:
`for (const key in countries) { if (key === "default") continue; ....`

Comment: logging countries[default] won't work.  Try countries["default"] or countries.default.

Comment: @TAHERElMehdi The OP has already explained that they know how to ignore `default` (`for (const key in countries) { if (key === "default") continue;`) 

Comment: What is your runtime environment? Does `import * as countries from "all-countries-and-cities-json" assert { type: 'json' };` help? It's a V8 feature. That means, it only works in Node.js and maybe in Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to not get a `default` entry in the object, import from JSON files using this syntax:

```js
import countries from "all-countries-and-cities-json";
```

It works in Node.js, I don't know about other runtimes.

Comment: ohhh, what an easy solution, thank you!